# Web API Route not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, http-status-code-404

I have :

```
[RoutePrefix("teamone/players")]

..........................
[HttpPost("{key:regex([A-Za-z0-9]{32})}/AccessToken", RouteName = "MakeToken")]
        public HttpResponseMessage MakeToken(string key)
        {
            key = key + "5555";
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

When I try to access this URL in Postman REST CLient:

```
http://localhost:4566/teamone/players/243445/AccessToken
```

I get a 404.

I do have

```
configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

What else I am missing? All the other routes in the same controller work correctly.

Comment: Are you using the attribute routing capability from MVC5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your regular expression is causing the input to be not matched. Also looks like you are still using RC version of Web API. We already have RTM version of Web API available publicly now and you should plan to upgrade to it. Attribute routing had gone through major changes from RC to RTM.

Following piece of code should help you identify if indeed your regular expression is matching the input. If it does match but web api doesn't, then the issue is with webapi, otherwise I think you should change your regular expression.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[A-Za-z0-9]{32}", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
bool isMatch = regex.IsMatch("243445");
```

Answer (score 2):

The **{32}** part of your regular expression means **exactly 32 characters**, but in your request that part of the Uri is only **six characters**.

Perhaps you meant something like **{6,32}** (meaning between 6 and 32 characters)?